# How to display data in blocks of a given size?

Tags: theming, 8

Is Drupal 8, which is shown in the accordion (module views_accordion) the terms of the taxonomy. By default, the module displays the list. I want to display in the blocks of a given size (as the picture)

[image]

In the module folder found twig template views-accordion-view.html.twig with the following content:

```
{% if title %}
  <h3 class="js-views-accodion-group-header">{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}

{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  {# A div wrapping the row content is required for the accordion to work #}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
      {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How to change it for my task? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

copy the file into your custom theme folder and change it in the manner you want , then clear the cache and drupal will use the new file instead